# ORDER BY enum integer field SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a UserInfo table with a column named [Type] with datatype integer and can contain below int values

```
     Employee -> 0
     FormerEmployee ->1
     Retiree -> 2
     Disabled -> 3
     COBRAParticipant -> 4
```

I am writing a sql query in which the User Type sort order should now be as follows:

```
Employee, COBRAParticipant, Disabled,Retiree, Former Employee.
```

using the below order by clause does not give expected result.

```
      order by CASE U.[Type]
        WHEN 0 THEN 'Employee'
        WHEN 1 THEN 'COBRAParticipant'
        WHEN 2 THEN 'Disabled'
        WHEN 3 THEN 'Retiree'
        WHEN 4 THEN 'FormerEmployee'
      END;
```

Can someone please suggest me the query.

Thanks!

Comment: Single quotes are for string literals. Use double quotes for column names.

Comment: What results *do* you get instead?

Comment: First you have `FormerEmployee ->1` and than `WHEN 1 THEN 'COBRAParticipant'`, actually only `Employee` is on its place

Comment: If you have an enumeration in c# you can cast variable to an integer, or use ToString() to get the string name of the enumeration.

Comment: Though this is under a C# application the question itself is pure sql. Consider removing the c# tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it

```
order by CASE U.[Type]
        WHEN 0 THEN 0
        WHEN 1 THEN 4
        WHEN 2 THEN 3
        WHEN 3 THEN 2
        WHEN 4 THEN 1
      END;
```